# For the 4x1 MUX shown below the Boolean Expression F(x,y,z) is

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, multiplexer, boolean-algebra

[image: Circuit diagram]

The output to a 4x1 MUX is : \$Y=S_1'S_0'I_0+S_1'S_0I_1+S_1S_0'I_2+S_1S_0I_3\$

My answer was : \$F=A_{1}'A_{2}'x+A_{1}'A_{2}x+A_{1}A_{2}'y+A_{1}A_{2}y' \Rightarrow xyz'+xyz+y'z\$

The correct answer is (a) \$xyz'\$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have omitted the `E` input in your equations!

What the \$E'\$ input does, is that it ANDs (multiplies) the result from your \$F\$ with \$E'\$, so the output equation would actually look like this:

\$F=(A_{1}'A_{2}'I_0+A_{1}'A_{2}I_1+A_{1}A_{2}'I_2+A_{1}A_{2}I_3)E'\$

From here, you should be able to see why did you get those extra \$xyz + y'z\$ terms that weren't in the correct answer!